# NodeJS (express) server restarts periodically

Tags: node.js, express, digital-ocean

I have a simple NodeJS application that is hosted on DigitalOcean.
For some reason that I cannot find, the app stops almost everyday.
The time when it happens is also suspiciously very accurate, about 08:30 AM.

I have checked that the DigitalOcean host is not being restarted.
Its uptime is few weeks. I have added some uncaught exception handler, hoping there is something that crashes the app but got nothing logged:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

The server is constantly monitored by UptimeRobot and until the "crash" I can see in the log it was working fine and the last logged request was the one sent by UptimeRobot.

I have another server for different environment which is configured pretty much the same and there it is even worse, it gets down about three times a day.

And the above doesn't look like being related to server workload at all. The one that is restarted three times a day is used for some feature checks, so it is almost unused.

And now I'm stuck. I don't know how to proceed with this problem.

Below you can find the script that I use to start the server:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp-server
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: MyApp backend server
### END INIT INFO

[ -f /etc/default/myapp-server ] && . /etc/default/myapp-server

user="myapp"
dir="/home/$user/web-server/repository/backend"
cmd="node app.js"

name="myapp-server"
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid"
stdout_log="/var/log/$name.log"
stderr_log="/var/log/$name.err"

get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already started"
    else
        echo "Starting $name"
        cd "$dir"
        #sudo -E -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log and $stderr_log"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
    if is_running; then
        echo -n "Stopping $name.."
        kill `get_pid`
        for i in {1..10}
        do
            if ! is_running; then
                break
            fi

            echo -n "."
            sleep 1
        done
        echo

        if is_running; then
            echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have   failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "Stopped"
            if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
                rm "$pid_file"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    if is_running; then
        echo "Unable to stop, will not attempt to start"
        exit 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
    status)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Running"
    else
        echo "Stopped"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

And here is my package list:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Sample description",
  "author": "Me",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.33",
    "npm": "1.4.28"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.9.8",
    "bookshelf": "^0.7.9",
    "cors": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "3.4.8",
    "jade": "*",
    "knex": "^0.7.3",
    "libphonenumber": "0.0.9",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.3",
    "node.extend": "^1.1.3",
    "nodemailer": "^1.3.4",
    "pg": "^4.2.0",
    "request": "^2.53.0",
    "ssl-root-cas": "^1.1.7",
    "xmlbuilder": "^2.6.1",
    "xoauth2": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Update: deployed with PM2**

I have deployed the app with PM2 and got nothing more from the log.
A sample just before the server has crashed:

```
HEAD / 302 5ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 3ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 5ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 2ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 12ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 3ms - 112b
GET /tmUnblock.cgi 400 1286ms - 1.14kb
GET / 302 9ms - 62b
HEAD / 302 6ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 11ms - 112b
Environment: development
Express server listening on port 3001
HEAD / 302 20ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 10ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 10ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 2ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 3ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 2ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 7ms - 112b
HEAD / 302 2ms - 112b
```

Nothing suspicious, just an attempt via missing **tmUnblock.cgi** security holes.

Comment: Check for memory leaks in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of VPS are your running RAM wise? Also what other processes are running on the server. I had an issue with Node (unrelated) where it would randomly stop working with no logging. The issue turned out to be memory usage. I'd suggest checking your memory usage with

```
free -m
```

Also I'd make sure you have a swap enabled to alleviate memory issues if this is the case. This tutorial will guide you on swap creation https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 assuming your on Ubuntu. A google search of how to create a swap with DO provides numerous results

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, seems that your answer matches my situation.

Comment: No problem glad I could be of help!